# Java - Values aren't reflecting after recursion call

Tags: java, recursion, backtracking

I ran into an issue while getting value for a `List<List<Integer>>` called res. It's a recursive call and that call is supposed to fill this "**res**", however when the recursive function is called by another function and that function is returning an empty list. But when I do log it, I can see the values. Here's the code:

```
class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> combinationSum(int[] arr, int k) {
        // given an arr and a sum k, find all the subsequences that sum upto k
            // we can use backtracking here as we need all the options
            // there are 2 choices for every element:
            // either we can take it in the subres or discard it
            // if we take it once, we can take it n times till the target is reached
            
            Arrays.sort(arr);
            List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<>();
            List<Integer> subRes = new ArrayList<>();

            combinationSum(0, arr, k, 0, res, subRes);

            return res;
    }
  
    public void combinationSum(int i, int[] arr, int k, int sum,
                                              List<List<Integer>> res, 
                                              List<Integer> subRes){
          if(sum == k) {
            if(!res.contains(subRes)) res.add(subRes);
            System.out.println("res = " + res);
            return;
          }

          if(i == arr.length || sum > k) return;

          subRes.add(arr[i]);
          sum += arr[i];
      
          combinationSum(i, arr, k, sum, res, subRes);

          subRes.remove(new Integer(arr[i]));
          sum -= arr[i];

          combinationSum(i + 1, arr, k, sum, res, subRes);
      
        }
}
```

I'm stuck badly on this,
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mutations you make to `subRes` in the recursion is affecting what you see in `res`. Before adding `subRes` into `res`, make a **new copy** of it.

```
 if(!res.contains(subRes)) {
     res.add(new ArrayList<>(subRes));
}
```

In your code, correct list (`subRes`) is added to `res`, but you mutate/modify `subRes` by removing elements sometime later when the recursive call returns.